# Alternating Row Colors on Qt Custom Models

Tags: qt, qt5

I am developing a Qt application that fetches and displays executions from the exchange. I am coloring rows that represent sells with red and buys with green. There is a requirement to have contiguous rows that represent same sides (e.g. buy or sell) to have slightly darker/lighter colors. I am using a custom model and overriding data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) function. Below is what handles coloring stuff:

```
...
const auto& execution = m_data[index.row()];

if(role == Qt::BackgroundRole) {
   const auto side = execution.side_;

   if(side == 'S') {
       return (index.row() & 1) ? QVariant(light_red_) : QVariant(lighter_red_);
   } else if(side == 'B') {
       return (index.row() & 1) ? QVariant(light_green_) : QVariant(lighter_green_);
   }
}
...
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see contiguous rows that belong to the same side sometimes have the same color. However, I would expect from my implementation to color lighter and darker in alternating rows. setAlternatingRowColors() is not suitable for me since I am coloring sides with different colors.

Edit: I am also using QSortFilterProxyModel and sorting view by a column in descending order.

Comment: Do you have a QSortFilterProxy model between your model and the view? Or do some sorting?

Comment: I am using QSortFilterProxyModel. I am also sorting view by a column in descending order. I am now suspecting that the ordering may be messing up with coloring logic

Comment: Correct - you can use a custom QStyledItemDelegate to set the normal/light color there because there you know the real (=number shown on the view) row number for your data.

Comment: why do I explicitly need a delegate for this? Why is model not sufficient to do this job? Even if I turn off sorting and not filtering anything, the problem persists, which was not what I was expecting.

Comment: If you don't sort and filter than the alternating rows do work - simply output the index.row() in one of your columns to see if you really don't sort and filter. If you filter you don't show all rows so your logic can not work, same goes for sorting - filtering and sorting does not change the row of the source data (it would be strange if it would though)

Comment: Just as an alternative to a custom delegate you could write your own 'colourizing' proxy model.  You'd need to ensure it was placed *between* the view and any sorting proxy.